# GSA key words to URLs through JAVA code

Tags: java, google-search-appliance

Hello I want to specify a keyword to a particular URL through java code.

Please suggest the approach how should I go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code which I was using to get the GSA response for the given keyword.

```
                        String gsaUrl = "http://yourAppliance/search?q=search keyword&client=default_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=default_frontend&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1&ulang=en&filter=0&site=default_collection&entqr=3&entqrm=3&num=20&start=0";
                        BufferedReader in = null;                       
                        URL url = new URL(gsaUrl);
                        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        StringBuffer gsaJsonResponse = new StringBuffer();

                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            gsaJsonResponse.append(inputLine);
                        }
```

Take care of exception and closing of stream.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I am trying a code in which i have to make a vonnection to com.google.enterprise.apis.client.GsaClient for which i have to give the URL port numberb and credentilas on doing so i am receiving following error    Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)

Comment: I guess you are using 8443 as port number.I tried connecting to GSA thru port 8000 and it was working.                   GsaClient client=  new GsaClient("your appliance host name",8000,"Admin Console username","Password");
       GsaEntry myEntry = client.getEntry("config", "crawlURLs");
       System.out.println("Start URLs: " + myEntry.getGsaContent("startURLs"));
       System.out.println("Follow URLs: " + myEntry.getGsaContent("followURLs")  );
       System.out.println("Do Not Crawl URLs: " + myEntry.getGsaContent("doNotCrawlURLs"));

Comment: For accessing GSA through 8000 port, you have to enable "HTTP (i.e. non SSL) Admin Console and Version Manager" under system setting on your GSA admin console.